# passing indefinite number of arguments to function without using an array

Tags: php, function, variables

I am having situation where i want to pass variables in php function.
The number of arguments are indefinite. I have to pass in the function without using the array.
Just like normal approach. Comma Separated.

like `test(argum1,argum2,argum3.....,..,,.,.,.....);`
 How i will call the function? Suppose i have an array array(1,2,3,4,5) containing 5 parameters. i want to call the function like func(1,2,3,4,5) . But the question is that, How i will run the loop of arguments , When calling the function. I tried func(implode(',',array)); But it is taking all return string as a one parameters

- In the definition, I also want the same format.
- I can pass variable number of arguments via array but i have to pass comma separated.
- I have to pass comma separated. But at the time of passing i don't know the number of arguments , They are in array.

Comment: RTLM: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Comment: Yes , I have gone through this, but my question is how to pass the variables? if i don't know the number of arguments, if they are in indefinite array.

Comment: you can simply pass the by separating with comma.

Comment: How, I will pass separating by comma. at run time ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the calling side, use [`call_user_func_array`](http://PHP.net/call_user_func_array).
Inside the function, use [`func_get_args`](http://PHP.net/func_get_args).

Since this way you're just turning an array into arguments into an array, I doubt the wisdom of this though. Either function is fine if you have an unknown number of parameters ***either*** when calling ***or*** receiving. If it's dynamic on both ends, why not just pass the array directly?!

Comment: Wow :) Thanks. This is what i am searchingfor call_user_func_array

Comment: I am creating a PHP framework and for the ease of user i am putting the parameters in function it self :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just define your function as

```
function test ()
```

then use the `func_get_args` function in php.

Then you can deal with the arguments as an array.

Example

```
function reverseConcat(){
      return implode (" ", array_reverse(func_get_args()));
}

echo reverseConcat("World", "Hello"); // echos Hello World
```

If you truely want to deal with them as though they where named parameters you could do something like this.

```
function getDistance(){
     $params = array("x1", "y1", "x2", "y2");
     $args = func_get_args();
     // trim excess params
     if (count($args) >  count($params) {
         $args = array_slice(0, count($params));
     } elseif (count($args) < count($params)){
         // define missing parameters as empty string
         $args = array_pad($args, count($params), "");
     } 
     extract (array_combine($params, $args));
     return sqrt(pow(abs($x1-$x2),2) + pow(abs($y1-$y2),2));

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Orangepill, But , How i will call the function? Suppose i have an array array(1,2,3,4,5) containing 5 parameters. i want to call the function like func(1,2,3,4,5) . But the question is that, How i will run the loop of arguments , When calling the function. I tried func(implode(',',array)); But it is taking all return string as a one parameters..

Comment: The way you do that is to use `call_user_func_array("reverseConcat", $array);`

Answer (score 2):

you can use :

```
$function_args = func_get_args();
```

inside your test() function definition .

Answer (score 0):

use this function:

```
  function test() {
      $args = func_get_args();
      foreach ($args as $arg) {
        echo "Arg: $arg\n";
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "same format." Do you mean same type, like they all have to be a string? Or do you mean they need to all have to meet some criteria, like if it's a list of phone numbers they need to be `(ddd) ddd-dddd`?

If it's the latter, you'll have just as much trouble with pre-defined arguments, so I'll assume you mean you want them all to be the same type.

So, going off of the already suggested solution of using `func_get_args()`, I would also apply `array_filter()` to ensure the type:

```
function set_names() {

    function string_only($arg) {

        return(is_string($arg));

    }

    $names_provided = func_get_args();  
    // Now you have an array of the args provided

    $names_provided_clean = array_filter($names_provided, "string_only"); 
    // This pulls out any non-string args

    $names = array_values($names_provided_clean); 
    // Because array_filter doesn't reindex, this will reset numbering for array.

     foreach($names as $name) {
           echo $name;
           echo PHP_EOL;
      }
}

set_names("Joe", "Bill", 45, array(1,2,3), "Jane");
```

Notice that I don't do any deeper sanity-checks, so there could be issues if no values are passed in, etc.

Answer (score -2):

You can use array also using explode http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php.

```
$separator = ",";
$prepareArray = explode ( $separator , '$argum1,$argum2,$argum3');
```

but be careful, **$argum1,$argum2,** etc should not contain , in value. You can overcome this by adding any separator. **$separator = "VeryUniqueSeparator";**
I don't have code so can't tell exact code. But manipulating this will work as your requirements.